# Why do I need to write ::shadow after :host?

Tags: polymer

I'm looking for an explanation as to why I would need to write :host::shadow in order for my inherited element to style elements in the shadow tree of my base element.

In the following sample code, I would like to be able to style the label for the complete element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-foo">
  <template>
      <style>
          :host label {
              color: red;
          }
      </style>
  <label>My label: </label>
  </template>
  <script>
     Polymer('my-foo');
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-bar" extends="my-foo">
  <template>
      <style>
          :host label {
              font-weight: bold;
          }
      </style>
      <shadow></shadow>
      <input />
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-bar');
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-bar></my-bar>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lz0Lcrx3/

The above example makes the label appear red but not bold. In order to fix it I need to change the style on my inherited element to include ::shadow.

```
  <style>
      :host::shadow label {
          font-weight: bold;
      }
  </style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lz0Lcrx3/1/

I know I'm dealing with two shadowroots in this case and I guess the ::shadow is to make sure we are applying the style to all of them, but I figured that :host would've been enough.

Can someone offer an explanation?

Comment: Hope this article by the Polymer Team helps: https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html

Comment: It doesn't really :( The ::shadow 'keyword' only gets mentioned in the "From outside the element" section. However, in this case I am not outside the element.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching I found the following article that I think explains this:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/

From what I understand, the `<shadow></shadow>` insertion point will make it necessary to use ::shadow from another shadowDOM tree since we are in fact crossing boundaries. Shadow boundaries that is, not element boundaries.